# Best ways to deal with merge conflicts for open source projects and other kinds of projects using Git

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution

When making PRs, sometimes I get merge conflicts when something is updated in the upstream repo.

At first, I just `git pull -r upstream master` as usual, but then I have to deal with the merge conflict.

I have no idea how I should start to understand the output of `git am --show-current-patch`, however,  I use Atom editor to resolve the conflicts before continuing the rebase.

The problem I face is that I can either use upstream changes which wipes away all of my work or at least in the section the conflict exists in the file. Or I use mine which does not apply any of the upstream changes.

So, what I do is re-clone the upstream repo, add all of my changes again and make the necessary commits, then I add my remote downstream repo/fork and force push my changes so the PR is updated.

This is long and tedious sometimes and I understand that this could be the only way, but I have to ask. Is there an easier more efficient way? Is the way I do it the only way to do it? Is this what most of the community does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 2):

> At first, I just `git pull -r upstream master` as usual, but then I have to deal with the merge conflict

That should be the correct process.
Regarding conflict, try and activate [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) in order to record your merge conflict resolutions: you won't have to repeat said resolution more than once.
See [Git Tools - Rerere](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere).